# Refresh vs Format

Tags: windows, toshiba-laptop

Can i recuperate my files or a way to undo the formatting?

I was on Control Panel

Trying to repair my WiFi connection.

Somehow i saw that option Refresh which i did not hesitate to click on and proceed.

After that all my computer did was it Formatted itself, (what i hated it) it is already a brand new Toshiba but had some very important documents in here.

Is there anyway to recover my documents?

Comment: Since your question has nothing to do with [tag:wireless-networking], except the context of when your fault happened, you should remove that tag from your question.

Comment: You didn't do a format so your documents should be there;

Answer (score 1):

Refresh reinstalls Windows but leaves your user folders in place; so, you've only lost the program files.